# Axios : call function after response

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm using Axios with React.js.
I want to call a function after the response of webservice. But it doesn't work, this is my code :

```
public onValidateRenammeNature = () => { // bouton valider, renomme la nature
  let id
  let newName
  console.log("this.state.myNature.id : " + this.state.myNature.id)
  id = this.state.myNature.id
  newName = this.refs.nature.getValue()

  axios.post('/UpdateNature', {            
    id: id,
    name: newName
  }).then(
  
  //here I want to call this function after the webservice is executed, but I don't know how can I do that
  this.getAllNaturesFromData()
  )

  this.setState({
    openRenammeNature: false,                
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.then()` function takes in a function as argument, you can do

```
axios.post('/UpdateNature', {            
            id: id,
            name: newName
        }).then(function(response){
            this.getAllNaturesFromData()
        })
//ES6 Arrow function work as well
axios.post('/UpdateNature', {            
            id: id,
            name: newName
        }).then((response) =>{
            this.getAllNaturesFromData()
        })
```

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't work for me ...  I've edited my code in an other answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to send an argument to `.then` function.

```
axios.post('/UpdateNature', {            
    id: id,
    name: newName
  }).then(function(res){
      if(res.statusCode === 200){
          this.getAllNaturesFromData();      // Your function call
      }
  })
```